# Bank System interface design - interview

Tags: design-patterns

My background: I am a recent graduate looking for job in software industry. 
Question: I was in recent interview with one of the software companies and was asked to draw UML diagram for a bank system which shows 2 accounts e.g. saving and checking and they have different way of calculating interest.

My Solution: I made an **Account** class an abstract class.
Like this: public abstract class Account{ ...... }
This class have 2 methods defined in it deposit() and withdraw() which is common to any account type.
another method CalculateInterest() which is abstract method.

2 classes saving and checking which extends account class and implement Account class. 
e.g: public class Saving extends Account { ... }

I added other class to top off UML like Bank and bank location but this did not satisfied interviewer and he wanted me to implement whole process as **INTERFACES** which i quite did not understood very well. I tried extracting same information but it did not pleased interviewer.

Any information that people out here can share will help me a lot in understanding design and further how to approach interviews.
I know their are lot of design patterns which are out there but when he mentioned about specific interfaces I was not sure how to approach that.

Comment: It seems like you had a perfectly fine answer, but the interviewer had some bee in their bonnet ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a normal banking process, you already give a fine answer. However for complex banking requirement, they will need more modular design, and that is where the interface will shine.

In your base design, you are sayint that:

- All Account can do Deposit
- All Account can do Withdraw
- All Account can CalculateInterest

Say with your current design, how if the requirement is:

1. To create a type of `account` that can only `deposit`. It cannot be withdrawn, only closed (such as time-based deposit)
2. To create a type of `account` that can only `withdraw`. Say that you `deposit` some money when opening the `account`, then you can only `withdraw`, and in the end, close it
3. To create a type of `account` that can only `CalculateInterest`, but not `deposit` or `withdraw`.
4. And so on

In your design, you may inherit the base `Account` class, and throw unimplement exception for each non-supported action (deposit, etc). However, (please correct me) that is violating LSP and risking for runtime exception.

Using interface based, you need to declare some interfaces:

- IAccount (this has basic property such as balance, user id, etc)
- IDepositable : IAccount
- IWithdrawable : IAccount
- IClosable : IAccount
- ICalculateInterestable : IAccount

Then for requirement, you can declare a class :

1. implementing IDepositable, IClosable, ICalculateInterestable
2. implementing IWithdrawable, IClosable, ICalculateInterestable
3. implementing IClosable, ICalculateInterestable

This may be not the neat-est design, but should suffice most of the banking requirement.

Comment: Also you can have separate implementations for interest calculation etc. A little bit of strategy.....

Comment: aaha!! interesting, Very nice explanation. I did managed to do something close to that but of-course this is much better. I got confused where to define basic operation like withdraw and deposit ? or all the classes which implement IDepositable and IWithdrawable will have their own definition of these operations ?

Comment: This kind of design will require `Composition over Inheritance` design to support reusable business logic. The explanation are quite long, so it will be better to search up the web for it.

Comment: This is very clever. IMHO, too clever. Designs should strive to minimize complexity while meeting requirements, and _likely_ future requirements. Unless you're reasonably sure that many combinations of depositable, withdrawable, and interestbearing are going to be desired, this design is harder to understand -> future maintainers are going to have a harder time modifying it (correctly). E.g. it is completely straightforward to create a new subclass that does not bear interest: override CalculateInterest such that it always returns 0!

Comment: With different point of view, interface is not more complex than inheritance, moreover it support expansion. Designing class services that accept interfaces can make it more reuseable. You can find some sources from stackoverflow about it.

Comment: Regarding `CalculateInterest` overriding, it is not a good API design. In some case, say that you has a logic to divide with result of `CalculateInterest`, it will always become division by zero exception. It is runtime exception, while designing with accepting `ICalculateInterestable` will give you compile error, providing you earlier error rather than waiting to be tested for error.