# Replacing functions with virtual methods considered harmful?

Tags: design-patterns

Let's say you have a bunch of functions that call each other. You'd like to test each of them in isolation. E.g. you should be able to test Foo without Bar being correct or even implemented. One solution is to turn those functions into virtual methods (or just regular methods if you're not using C++). E.g.

```
class K {
 public:
  virtual int Foo();
  virtual int Bar();   // called by Foo

  // No member variables.
};
```

Now, you can do this in test:

```
// You could use googlemock instead of this.
class KFoo : public K {
 public:
  virtual int Bar() {
    return 42;
  }
};

// googletest
TEST(K, Foo) {
  std::unique_ptr<K> k(new KFoo);
  assert(k->Foo() == 7);  // Bar gets called, and returns 42.
}
```

This is odd for a couple of reasons though:

1. K has no member variables; it is "stateless".
2. You need to `new K` in order to call anything.

Is this a good idea? Does this already have a name? Obviously, virtual slows things down, but IIUC, unless you're making tons of calls, the performance impact is small (and you know what they say about premature optimization). I'm much more interested in how this will affect maintainability, testability, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be sure in C++, however I have experience in C# (full OOP).

I think in C#, the design you mentioned above is abstract class / inheritance. If I'm not mistaken, your design in C++ will become like this in C#:

```
public class K{
    public virtual int Foo(){
        return Bar();
    }
    public virtual int Bar(){
        // actual code
    }
}

public class KFoo : K{
    public override int Bar(){
        return 42;
    }
}
```

This kind of design is a basic in OOP, so it is not harmful. However, it will become more complex as more inheritance is added (K2 inherit K, K3 inherit K2, etc..). As additional info, you can read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930374/bank-system-interface-design-interview/16930778#16930778) explaining my point of view about why sometimes inheritance / class based method sometimes is not as modular as you think.

IMHO, it will be modular if you inject the "service" class instead of defining inheritance, it is called composition over inheritance.

```
public class KBarService : IKBarService{
    public int Bar(){
        // actual code
    }
}
public class KBarServiceMock : IKBarService{
    public int Bar(){
        return 42;
    }
}
public class K{
    public K(IKBarService service){
        this.service = service;
    }
    IKBarService service;

    public int Foo(){
        return Bar();
    }
    public int Bar(){
        return service.Bar();
    }
}
```

You can do the same for the `Foo()`. With this design, you can reuse the `KBarService` in other class, even that class is not a derived class form K.

Comment: K is not an abstract class; it has implementations for its methods. They're just not shown, and users of K new K in order to call those implementations.

Comment: Another thing: K is not designed for inheritance. Inheritance is only used to test.

Comment: Right, I also not state anything for K being an abstract class. virtual in C# is also not abstract, it has implementation.

Comment: K's design may not to be inherited, but once the business logic expanding and you need to expand K (but keep the original used), you will need inheritance. `Composition over inheritance` and `Dependency Injection` can help to solve the business expansion issue.